# Answer to "아저씨，이 공책 세 권 주세요"

Tags: grammar, spoken-korean, conversation

> A 아저씨，이 공책 세 권 주세요. 
>  B --------------------------
>
> a) 네，여기 있습니다. 
> b) 네，세 권 있습니다.

I am doing some exercises to understand more about grammars and vocabulary. For the dialogue above, the answer is the option a. However, I am wondering if the option b also works.

Could anyone share your opinion? Thanks.

Comment: a && b works
a) more focused on what he deliver
b) just mentioned quantity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

여기 있습니다 is idiomatic, translates to "here you go".

세 권 있습니다 is "there are three", so it's a bit unnatural to say that in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

Bad exercise.

If that is a "one or more answer" question, then I, a Korean only educated in Korea, might choose both after 5 minutes of consideration.
If not, a) is the right answer for education purpose explaining different usage of "있습니다".

In real life, b) also could be the natural conversation.

```
네，세 권 (여기) 있습니다.
```